# Generating and writing binary data to stream in Node.js

Tags: node.js, binaryfiles, binary-data

I want to generate some binary data in my Node.js application and then write it to an HTTP response for the client to download. My current implementation of the same application is in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), which achieves this using [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html). For example,

```
import struct
# ...
s = 'Filename header'
s_binary = struct.pack('15s',s)
# ...
```

Also, how do I convert numbers into binary in Node.js? The way I do it in Python is:

```
# To convert a float into four byte binary representation in Python.
import struct
num_binary = struct.pack('f',23.33)
```

How do I do the same thing in Node.js?

This is so far the best solution I've got - straight port of Python's struct library to Node.js - [jspack](https://github.com/pgriess/node-jspack).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Bison](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/BiSON.js/). It's like JSON but creates binary data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var s="Filename header";
var s_binary=new Buffer(15);
for(var i=0;i<s_binary.length;i++) {
    s_binary[i]=0;
}
s_binary.write(s);
// Now you can write s_binary to a stream.
```

Comment: ok this might work. Do you know how to convert numbers into binary? Let me update the question with an example in python.

Comment: good solution. Except you don't need to fill with nulls if you're going to immediately fill the buffer with text.

Comment: you can write buffers to streams, eg from the http example, you can do res.end(myBuffer). To send only the first 8 bytes of the buffer: res.end(myBuffer.slice(0, 8));

Comment: @JasonWoof: Actually, it is necessary. The Python code will pad the string with null bytes if the string is less than 15 characters. If left uninitialized in node.js, it will be full of junk bytes.

Comment: but it's not less than 15 characters

Comment: also, I've recently discovered you can just do: var s_binary = new Buffer(s);

Comment: @JasonWoof: I assumed `"Filename header"` was just a placeholder and could vary based on user input.

Comment: @icktoofay: The way I see it, you either figure out exactly how big you need the buffer to be, then make it that big, or you make a buffer that's bigger than you'll need, and keep track of how much of it you've used. You should never output the part you didn't use, so I don't see how it matters what bytes are in that part.

Comment: @JasonWoof: I believe some protocols require a field to be a specific length and padded by null bytes. I assumed this question was related to one.

Comment: @icktoofay: ahh, he does seem to be putting text characters into a fixed length field. Sorry I'm too absorbed in my own code to notice.